# Plotting histogram with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

i try to plot data in a histogram or bar in python. The data size (array size) is between 0-10000. The data itself (each entry of the array) depends on the input and has a range between 0 and e+20 (mostly the data is in th same range). So i want to do a hist plot with matplotlib. I want to plot how often a data is in some intervall (to illustrate the mean and deviation). Sometimes it works like this: 
[hist1](http://i41.tinypic.com/e0sjcz.png).
But sometimes there is a problem with the intevall size like this:
[hist2](http://i40.tinypic.com/2ivdvs9.jpg).
In this plot i need more bars at point 0-100 etc.
Can anyone help me with this?

The plots are just made with:

```
from numpy.linalg import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(numbers,bins=100)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `hist` produces a plot with an x range that covers the full range of your data.
If you have one outsider at very high x in comparison with the other values, then you will see this image with a 'compressed' figure.

I you want to have always the same view you can fix the limits with `xlim`.
Alternatively, if you want to see your distribution always centered and as nicer as possible, you can calculate  the mean and the standard deviation of your data and fix the x range accordingly (p.e. for mean +/- 5 stdev)