# Why isn't my matplotlib histogram plotting in PyCharm from Tweepy acquired data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, tweepy, sentiment-analysis

I have code for a Twitter streamer that performs sentiment analysis on tweets that go into a CSV file. The sentiment analysis results are then plotted on a pie chart, and what I'd like to do is also plot these on a histogram too. I've looked at a couple of posts here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736978/plotting-histogram-with-matplotlib)(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47538718/histogram-plotting-matplotlib) and a YouTube vid on how to do it and can't understand why it's not working. I'll post the whole code so you can see everything it's doing but the code for the charts is very near the bottom.

The error I receive is, "AttributeError: 'SentimentAnalysis' object has no attribute 'plotHist'" but it's laid out exactly the same as the pie chart and this plots fine. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong please?

```
import csv
import re
import sys
import tweepy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from textblob import TextBlob
import sqlite3 as lite
# import models.py - was a file with CREATE statement in for SQLite
global db
global cursor


class SentimentAnalysis:

    def __init__(self):
        self.tweets = []  # initialising empty list objects
        self.tweetText = []
        # self.api = tweepy.API(self.auth)

    # Change access details below to point to own application
    def download_data(self):
        # authenticating
        consumerKey = '************'
        consumerSecret = '************'
        accessToken = '************'
        accessTokenSecret = '************'
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumerKey, consumerSecret)
        auth.set_access_token(accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
        # api = tweepy.API(auth)
        api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

        # input for term to be searched and how many tweets to search
        searchTerm = input("Enter Keyword/Tag to search about: ")
        NoOfTerms = int(input("Enter how many tweets to search: "))

        # searching for tweets
        self.tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=searchTerm, lang="en").items(NoOfTerms)

        # Open/create a file to append data to
        csvFile = open('result.csv', 'a')

        # Use csv writer
        csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

        # creating variables to store info
        polarity = 0
        positive = 0
        wpositive = 0
        spositive = 0
        negative = 0
        wnegative = 0
        snegative = 0
        neutral = 0

        # iterating through tweets fetched
        for tweet in self.tweets:
            # Append to temp so that we can store in csv later. I use encode UTF-8
            self.tweetText.append(self.clean_tweet(tweet.text).encode('utf-8'))
            # print (tweet.text.translate(non_bmp_map))    #print tweet's text
            analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
            # print(analysis.sentiment)  # print tweet's polarity
            polarity += analysis.sentiment.polarity  # adding up polarities to find the average later

            if analysis.sentiment.polarity == 0:  # adding reaction of how people are reacting to find average later
                neutral += 1
            elif 0 < analysis.sentiment.polarity <= 0.3:
                wpositive += 1
            elif 0.3 < analysis.sentiment.polarity <= 0.6:
                positive += 1
            elif 0.6 < analysis.sentiment.polarity <= 1:
                spositive += 1
            elif -0.3 < analysis.sentiment.polarity <= 0:
                wnegative += 1
            elif -0.6 < analysis.sentiment.polarity <= -0.3:
                negative += 1
            elif -1 < analysis.sentiment.polarity <= -0.6:
                snegative += 1

        # Write to csv and close csv file
        csvWriter.writerow(self.tweetText)
        csvFile.close()  # delete this for the insert SQL code bit

        # Attempt at SQLite code, couldn't get it right
        # con = lite.connect(r"C:\\Users\\Student User\\PycharmProjects\\DataScienceLabs\\tweets.db")
        # cur = con.cursor()
        # cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE tweets(created_at text, id_str text, text text)''')
        # commented out as models.py creates database

        # cur.execute("INSERT INTO tweets(?, ?, ?)", (created_at,
                                                    # id_str,
                                                    # text))

        # con.commit()

        # finding average of how people are reacting
        positive = self.percentage(positive, NoOfTerms)
        wpositive = self.percentage(wpositive, NoOfTerms)
        spositive = self.percentage(spositive, NoOfTerms)
        negative = self.percentage(negative, NoOfTerms)
        wnegative = self.percentage(wnegative, NoOfTerms)
        snegative = self.percentage(snegative, NoOfTerms)
        neutral = self.percentage(neutral, NoOfTerms)

        # finding average reaction
        polarity = polarity / NoOfTerms

        # printing out data
        print("How people are reacting on " + searchTerm + " by analyzing " + str(NoOfTerms) + " tweets.")
        print()
        print("General Report: ")

        if polarity == 0:
            print("Neutral")
        elif 0 < polarity <= 0.3:
            print("Weakly Positive")
        elif 0.3 < polarity <= 0.6:
            print("Positive")
        elif 0.6 < polarity <= 1:
            print("Strongly Positive")
        elif -0.3 < polarity <= 0:
            print("Weakly Negative")
        elif -0.6 < polarity <= -0.3:
            print("Negative")
        elif -1 < polarity <= -0.6:
            print("Strongly Negative")

        print()
        print("Detailed Report: ")
        print(str(positive) + "% people thought it was positive")
        print(str(wpositive) + "% people thought it was weakly positive")
        print(str(spositive) + "% people thought it was strongly positive")
        print(str(negative) + "% people thought it was negative")
        print(str(wnegative) + "% people thought it was weakly negative")
        print(str(snegative) + "% people thought it was strongly negative")
        print(str(neutral) + "% people thought it was neutral")

        self.plotPieChart(positive, wpositive, spositive, negative, wnegative, snegative, neutral, searchTerm,
                          NoOfTerms)
        self.plotHist(positive, wpositive, spositive, negative, wnegative, snegative, neutral)

    def clean_tweet(self, tweet):
        # Remove links, special characters, etc., from tweet
        return ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t]) | (\w +:\ / \ / \S +)", " ", tweet).split())

    # function to calculate percentage
    def percentage(self, part, whole):
        temp = 100 * float(part) / float(whole)
        return format(temp, '.2f')

    def plotPieChart(self, positive, wpositive, spositive, negative, wnegative, snegative, neutral, searchTerm, noOfSearchTerms):
        labels = ['Positive [' + str(positive) + '%]', 'Weakly Positive [' + str(wpositive) + '%]','Strongly Positive [' + str(spositive) + '%]', 'Neutral [' + str(neutral) + '%]',
                  'Negative [' + str(negative) + '%]', 'Weakly Negative [' + str(wnegative) + '%]', 'Strongly Negative [' + str(snegative) + '%]']
        sizes = [positive, wpositive, spositive, neutral, negative, wnegative, snegative]
        colors = ['yellowgreen', 'lightgreen', 'darkgreen', 'gold', 'red', 'lightsalmon', 'darkred']
        patches, texts = plt.pie(sizes, colors=colors, startangle=90)
        plt.legend(patches, labels, loc="best")
        plt.title('How people are reacting on ' + searchTerm + ' by analyzing ' + str(noOfSearchTerms) + ' Tweets.')
        plt.axis('equal')
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.show()

    def plotHsit(self, positive, wpositive, spositive, negative, wnegative, snegative, neutral):
        sentiments = [positive, wpositive, spositive, negative, wnegative, snegative, neutral]
        plt.hist(sentiments)
        plt.show()


if __name__== "__main__":
    # db_init()
    sa = SentimentAnalysis()
    sa.download_data()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling:

```
self.plotHist(...)
```

Your method definition:

```
def plotHsit(self, ...):
```

Notice how they are not the same. Hence the error about it not knowing what `plotHist` (<-> `plotHsit`) is.

Comment: But this is the same case for the pie chart and that plots fine. Could you tell me what I need to change to get it working please?

Comment: There is no typo/spelling mistake with `plotPieChart`. The change you need to make is give them identical names.

Comment: Haha I can't believe I didn't see that even when you pointed it out, I clearly need to sleep more, thank you!

Comment: After fixing this my charts now generate but superimposed on one another. Would you know how to fix this please?